# How do I implement drag and drop on a canvas?

Tags: java, javafx

More specifically, how would I go about implementing a drag and drop feature so that the image file dragged on to the canvas would be drawn on the canvas? I've tried using a `VBox` listener on top of the canvas, but that didn't work. The source code of by program is available [here](https://github.com/thecarterb/JPaint).

In my controllers `initialize()` function, I have the following code. `canvas` is passed from the FXML file via the `@FXML` annotation:

```java
public void initialize() {
        GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // Setter for brush type
        setBrushBrush();

        // Get screen dimensions and set the canvas accordingly
        Dimension screenSize = getScreenSize();
        double screenWidth = screenSize.getWidth();
        double screenHeight = screenSize.getHeight();
        canvas.setHeight(screenHeight/1.5);
        canvas.setWidth(screenWidth/1.5);

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
         //Drawing code here
        }); 

        canvas.setOnDragOver(e -> {
         // Need to read data of dragged image
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseDragReleased(e -> {
         // Need to put dragged data on to canvas
        });
}
```

Comment: Post code in your question, instead of posting a link to it. In this case (since there is a lot of code) you should create a minimal version of your application (a [MCVE]) for the purposes of showing the issue in the question. The short answer is that you should register drag over and drag dropped handlers on your canvas. (I don't know what a `VBox` listener is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mouseDragReleased` event is the wrong event to listen for here. That event is triggered when the mouse is released during a "full press-drag-release gesture" within the application; not when data is dropped during a "platform-supported drag-and-drop gesture" (see the [documentation for `MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) for a description of these different dragging modes). So instead of `canvas.setOnMouseDragReleased(...)`, you need:

```
canvas.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
    // ...
});
```

Assuming the implementations of the handlers are correct, this should enable you to drop an image from a file and draw it on the canvas.